# Firefox iMacros suddenly stop working for me

Tags: imacros

I need help. I just opened up my firefox to continue off where I left off last time and my scripts doesn't work. The default scripts doesn't work either. When I click Javascript scripts, it gives me a TypeError: listener is not a non-null object.

I restarted my computer and I reinstalled the addons, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you, by chance, made an update to Firefox itself? Browser updates crash Imacros all the time

Comment: I don't remember doing it. That's what I was speculating too. How do I reverse the process? Do I have to reinstall the whole browser? Or can I just do a rollback?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I did all the tipical things (uninstall the extension, uninstall the browser from windows and nothing worked so I did a "FireFox Refresh" from the Mozilla support then Intalled iMacros again and it worked.

Refresh Firefox here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

I suggest  you to make a backup of the macros files you have saved.

I suggest  you to make a backup of the macros files you have saved.

Comment: Cool thanks, but in the end, I also uninstall the current firefox and imacros. wipe everything clean (deleting the profile data) and then installed specific versions of firefox and imacros that previously worked for me. Then I disabled all the automatic updates to make sure it doesn't break again.